# Using Java mail Pop3 cannot seem to delete emails from Gmail

Tags: java, email, gmail

I have a java program that acts as a POP3 client using javax.mail.  I am able to list and retrieve the contents of a Gmail inbox no problem.  However, I cannot seem to delete emails.  Here is the (important parts of the) code:

```
POP3Store sto=... another method creates and connects the POP3Store
Folder ibx=sto.getFolder("INBOX");
ibx.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

Message[] msgarr=ibx.getMessages();

for(int mi=0; mi<msgarr.length; mi++) {
    ...do stuff with the message
    msgarr[mi].setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
    }
ibx.close(true); //folder.close(true) indicates to expunge the folder
sto.close();
```

After running this and seeing it handle each message, I go into Gmail and the emails are still there, and even showing as unread.  If I re-run the java client, it will see and handle the same emails.

This same code happily deletes emails from an exchange server.

How can I get Gmail to delete emails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gmail handles POP deletion specially.

You can configure what Gmail should do when a message is deleted through POP in Gmail Settings, on the `Forwarding and POP / IMAP` tab.

Comment: Oh yeah!  Actually, I have known this before!  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As SLaks says, Gmail is a special case where it has its own settings for controlling deletion that override whatever the client wants to do.

It can be edited in the `Forwarding and POP / IMAP`

However, I want to add that for a message to be considered "downloaded" by Gmail, you need to have retrieved the content of each message, and in the case of multipart message types, the content of each part within that message.

Here's some example code that I use to force the deletion of unwanted messages from Gmail:

```
// Grab the content to get the email off the server
// folder is of type javax.mail.Folder and is already in the correct state to get messages from the mail store (Gmail)
Message msg = folder.getMessage(1);
Multipart multipart = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
int partcount = multipart.getCount();
for (int count = 0; count < partcount; count++) {
    multipart.getBodyPart(count);
}
```

Comment: Did use the snipe code above with an inbox from Microsoft outlook and fix the deletion problem

Answer (score 0):

If you prepend **"recent:"** in your pop3 username you will solve.
Example: **recent:yourusername@gmail.com**

This connects to gmail using [Recent Mode](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/47948?hl=en)