# Unable to delete email by using JavaxMail with POP3 server

Tags: java, pop3

I have been using the JavaxMail pop3 server to read user email inboxes. At times though I deleted the message after processing still can able to read the message. In fact, it's not actually deleting the message so the server is processing the same message multiple times.

here is a sample code snippet

```
         Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
         folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

         // fetches new messages from the server
         Message[] messages = folderInbox.getMessages();
         for(Message msg : messages){
           try {
              if(!msg.getFolder().isOpen()) {   //Determine whether to open specific message folder
                 msg.getFolder().open(Folder.READ_WRITE); //If close, reopen 
              }

              prcocessMessage(msg);
              msg.setFlag(Flag.DELETED, true);
           } catch(Throwable ex) {
                //If exception happens message will not be deleted
                logger.error("Unexpected Exception: ", ex);
           }
        }
        // disconnect
        folderInbox.close(true);
        store.close();
```

I have tried using the saveChanges() on the message after deleting, but couldn't achieve the result. How can stop multiple processing for a single email?

Comment: Did you get any exceptions in the log?

Comment: Are you using a Gmail mailbox?   If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084944.

Comment: @StephenC, thank you for responding, I didn't find any exception and this issue is happening with the Zoho mailbox with few emails, not for complete inbox.